# My USB head phoness only let me use skype

Tags: windows-7, audio, browser, skype, usb-headset

My USB headphones (microsoft lifechat LX-3000) only let me here skype and my computers programe to test if your speakerss/  headphones are working. i can get it to sound off a browser or my games please help.i'm running on windows seven

Answer (score 1):

Set it to the default audio device (not just default communications device) in the sound "Playback Devices" menu.